# What do I need to know before I develop a health related software in EU?

Tags: wordpress

I have a client who needs to collect some health-related data, store it and analyse it. Everything will be done through their website. That is based on Wordpress
.
I learned there is HIPPA standard on how to process and work with such data. All data journey from the uploading person, processing software, cloud and the person analysing it hast to be HIPPA compliant, right?

However, I see no references for it in GDPR or any other EU regulations on data protection.
No idea what to do about it now. Maybe someone could share experience on how to develop a health-related app according to Europe regulations?

It is important that my client's customers feel safe sharing their sensitive data.

Thank you

Comment: It's unclear how you've come to the conclusion that HIPAA governs your (seemingly entirely) EU-based software; do you mind extrapolating on that a bit? In any case, a more pointed version of this question may be a better fit for [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I was more hoping on answer form the developer's standpoint.

Comment: I read about HIPPA on the internet. After a bit more research I found that it applies only to the USA. And now I am lost